# How to use multithreading efficiently in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, image-processing

I'm writing a tool with a WPF GUI in VB.Net which processes a lot of image files.
To speed this thing a little bit up and to watch the current processing image, I want to start using threads.
I have several folders which contain again several folders, which contain several files. Can I queue a new Thread to the ThreadPool for each image or is it more efficient to start a thread which processes a folder/subfolder?
My first idea was to start two BackgroundWokers and let each handle half of the top-level folders. But this is not very clever in case I have only one top-level folder and I can only give a bad estimate on how many images have been processed already.
Do you have any genral tips on how to use which type of threading in VB.Net? I couldn't find something appropriate concerning efficiency and scenarios.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx) I think this will satisfy your need

Comment: Adding threads doesn't make a hard drive faster.  Your machine can easily have more than one cpu core but you still only have a single drive.  You could only be ahead by using one thread to read the image files, another thread to process them so that reading and processing can overlap.  Do not bother if the cpu load of your current program is less than 30%

Comment: Thanks DoanCuong, the link was quite helpful!
Although my current problem is the CPU load, I really appreciate your advice HansPassant. It's an interesting concept of improving performance!